# Proof of divisibility by full induction

Tags: induction, divisibility

How can I prove by full induction that $n^{2(p+1)}-1$ is divisible by $n+1$?

Comment: $n^{2(p+1)}\equiv (-1)^{2(p+1)}=1\bmod n+1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- $n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)\qquad$
- Consider $n^{2(p+1)}-n^{2p}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If $n^x\equiv1\bmod{n+1}$, and $n^2\equiv1\bmod{n+1}$, then $n^{x+2}\equiv1\bmod{n+1}$.